# javascript: for different objects of same class copy arrays in different variables

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype

in following code I declare two objects of class "person".
problem is that when for one of the variables ("Courses") I use push method to update its values so they are  copied in **proto** and as a consequence both objects share same "Courses" array inside there **proto**. i want them to have there own unique arrays.

```
var person = {
    Name: "John",
    Grade: 0,
    Courses:[],
    setGrade : function(y){
        this.Grade=y;
    },
    setCourse:function(t){
        this.Courses.push(t);

    },
}

var grade9 = Object.create(person);
grade9.setCourse("eng");
grade9.setCourse("math");
grade9.setGrade(9);

var grade10 = Object.create(person);
grade10.setCourse("phy");
grade10.setCourse("chem");
grade10.setCourse("bio");
grade10.setGrade(10);
```

[debug output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qapx.png)

thanx.

Comment: I think you should read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Object.create` returns an object with the prototype property set to the passed-in object. The 'instance' objects delegate to the prototype. The *same* prototype. In C terms they all have pointers to the same struct (the prototype) and modifying it changes the value for all the 'instance' objects (they're only pointing to it). While that isn't totally accurate its enough so for our purposes here. If you want them to all to have independent copies you'll have to add them:

```
personFactory = function() {
    newPerson = Object.create(person);
    newPerson.array = [];
}

myPerson = personFactory();
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a factory method, and inside overshadow the property with a specific property for the current instance:

```
function createNewPerson() {
    return Object.create(person, { // object.create with propertiesObject to overshadow original Courses property 
        Courses: { writable: true, configurable: true, value: [] }
    });
}

var grade9 = createNewPerson();
grade9.setCourse("eng");
grade9.setCourse("math");
grade9.setGrade(9);

var grade10 = createNewPerson();
grade10.setCourse("phy");
grade10.setCourse("chem");
grade10.setCourse("bio");
grade10.setGrade(10);
```